# Set value to a new datetime column in a table with over 5 million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table named Example that has a over 5M rows.
I want to know the most efficient way to create a new `DateTime` column that does not allow nulls and has a default value of Now. just setting the value would fail due to the amount of rows.

The plan I have in mind would involve:

1) creating a new column that allows nulls.

```
ALTER TABLE Example
ADD RecordDate datetime
GO
```

2) set the value of the column to `GETDATE()` 1000 (or more if possible) rows at a time.

3) once all rows have a value, I would alter the column to not allow nulls.

```
ALTER TABLE Example
ALTER COLUMN RecordDate datetime NOT NULL
```

I am not sure on what would be the most efficient way of completing step number 2. so that is what I would like some tips on.

Comment: What clustered index do you have on the table?

Comment: @Elliveny just the PK, called ID

Comment: Why dont you add both conditions i.e Default value GETDATE and NOT NULL at the time of adding column.

Comment: Can you calculate ranges from ID that would be a good amount of rows to update at once, and run few updates like that?

Comment: JamesZ - my thinking too

Comment: @Elliveny it is a bigint

Comment: @PareshJ that would block the table fail after a long time

Comment: @JamesZ that would be a great option, I just dont know how to go about doing it correctly.

Comment: @mmilan if your IDs are distributed even fairly evenly, just calculate ranges in excel, and run the update with "... set RecordDate = getdate() where ID >= XXX and ID < YYY"

Comment: What version of sql-server? For 2012 and later versions, `ADD` column with a default value (that is a runtime constant) is an online operation that writes only metadata, and is really fast.

Comment: @ypercube thanks! I did not know that but this is for SQL2008R2, it is still nice to know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work though a large table with a sequential ID, applying updates in batches, this approach will work:

```
DECLARE @startID bigint
DECLARE @endID bigint

SELECT @startID=min(ID) from Example

WHILE @startID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
  SELECT @endID=MAX(ID) FROM (
    SELECT top(1000) ID from Example where ID>=@startID ORDER BY ID
  ) t

  update Example
  set RecordDate = GETDATE()
  where ID between @startID and @endID AND RecordDate IS NULL

  IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 BEGIN
    SET @startID=NULL
  END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @startID=@endID
  END
END
```

The batch size is controlled by

```
SELECT top(1000) ID from Example where ID>=@startID ORDER BY ID
```

Adjust the 1000 as necessary to ensure each UPDATE completes quickly. I've used this technique to update hundreds of millions of rows in batches of around 100000 per update.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure on how to do this efficiently in SQL

Comment: The key thing is to keep the UPDATE short, by making use of the clustered index on a sequential value. This procedure can still hit a db server quite hard, so if you're happy to let it tick through a little more slowly you can take the pressure off the machine by adding a WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.5' (for example) before the final END statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
ALTER TABLE Example ADD COLUMN RecordDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
```

No matter how you attempt this, you are going to have to rewrite all the data records to add the extra bytes on each page for the value -- even if the value is NULL.

I had a thought that the following would minimize changes to the data:

```
ALTER TABLE Example ADD _RecordDate datetime;

ALTER TABLE Example ADD FirstDateTime as (cast(<current datetime> as datetime));

ALTER TABLE Example ADD RecordDate as COALESCE(_RecordDate, FirstDateTime);
```

On second thought, you still have to reserve the space on the page for `_RecordDate`, so the first method is probably the best.

Another alternative would be to set up another table with the same primary key and the record date.  This requires a `left join` to get the information, but that would only be needed when you are accessing the column.

Comment: Thats what exactly i suggested to OP.

Comment: That will probably cause a long table lock while every row is updated. Also the implicit transaction will make the transaction log grow huge.

Comment: @DBNull yeah, that is more or less why I am trying to find a more efficient solution

Comment: For 2012+ versions, add column with a default (that is runtime constant) is a metadata only operation. really fast. See: [Table size is not changed after new column is added](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90546/table-size-is-not-changed-after-new-column-is-added)

Answer (score 0):

mmilan

You can try this script on step #1:

```
ALTER TABLE Example ADD RecordDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Now you don't need the step #2 and #3.

Comment: No offense but this approach has been proposed twice already and rejected for what I think is good reason.